# Running a recursive asynchronous function in dart

Tags: recursion, flutter, dart

I am using Microsoft Graph to get a list of `mailFolders` that a user has. Each `mailFolder` has the opportunity to have a number of child folders, and these child folders get split up into tens so as to follow Microsoft's rules on making large API calls. I am attempting to make an object that will include all of a person's folders and all of their child folders and their child folders and so on - it needs to be a recursive process. Currently I am returning `List<MailFolder>` which will be the list of mail folders a user has, but a `MailFolder` looks like this, note that it contains a list of itself:

```
class MailFolder {
  String name = "";
  int unreadCount = 0;
  int totalCount = 0;
  String id = "";
  List<MailFolder> childFolders = new List<MailFolder>();

  MailFolder(this.name, this.unreadCount, this.totalCount, this.id, this.childFolders);
}
```

My function then has to run itself again to fill up a folders childFolders property. It seems as though dart does not let you run recursive processes if you have to await them, as I get no errors but when execution reaches the call to itself it instantly ends the current execution of the function and leaves. Is this a problem with the way I have written my code or is this a functionality that dart does not have? Below is the extract of code for getting the folders:

```
Future<List<MailFolder>> getFolders(String request) async {
  var response;
  var data;
  List<MailFolder> folder = new List<MailFolder>();
  var prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  response = await http.get(
      Uri.encodeFull(request), 
      headers: {"Authorization":"Bearer " + "Access Token" });
  data = JsonDecoder().convert(response.body);
  while(data["@odata.nextLink"] != null) {
    for (int i = 0; i < data["value"].length; i++) {
      folder.add(new MailFolder (
        data["value"][i]["displayName"],
        data["value"][i]["unreadItemCount"],
        data["value"][i]["totalItemCount"],
        data["value"][i]["id"],
        await getFolders("https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/mailFolders/" + folder[i].id + "/childFolders"),
      ));
    }
    response = await http.get(
      Uri.encodeFull(data["@odata.nextLink"]),
        headers: {"Authorization":"Bearer " + "Access Token"});
    data = JsonDecoder().convert(response.body);
  }
  for (int i = 0; i < data["value"].length; i++) {
    folder.add(new MailFolder (
      data["value"][i]["displayName"],
      data["value"][i]["unreadItemCount"],
      data["value"][i]["totalItemCount"],
      data["value"][i]["id"],
      await getFolders("https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/mailFolders/" + folder[i].id + "/childFolders"),
    ));
  }
  return folder;
}
```

Comment: Could it be that the first time you call folder[i], the folder list is empty?

Comment: @PabloBarrera You could be right... Is it better practice to make the `MailFolder` with `new List<MailFolder>` and then after the creation update what the list contains?

Comment: I think you could use data["value"][i]["id"] instead of folder[i].id, right?

Comment: @PabloBarrera I can definitely do that - I'm just worried that creating a folder by awaiting a component of said folder might not be the most processor conscious way to do it. Is it better to make the folder and then edit the list of folders within it or is it better to do it as I am doing it with the replacement of using data["value"][I]["id"]?

Comment: It depends of how you want to use the list, in this case it seems you want to interact with the list or show the list only when it's fully completed so it's okay to await. But if you wanted to just show the current folder and get the sub folders only when the users click on that folder, or if you wanted to show the current folder and then get only the current sub folders or all the sub folders on background, you could make the folder and then edit the list sub folders (in these cases, using streams could be helpful)

Comment: I am also facing the same error. Calling a function ends the execution and starts a new one. I don't even use await. So, this might be because dart don't support it.